# Chi-square for proportion/percentage of M/F in two different groups

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, chi-squared-test

I'm attempting to figure out how to do a chi-square based on gender in two different groups.

Overall, my data has two different groups that I'm dealing with, with a column for what drug the person is taking (`drug_1` and `drug_2`), and another for their sex (`M` or `F`).

The main issue with using a normal Chi-square test that I have come across is that the two groups are relatively uneven (145 in `drug_1` and 94 in `drug_2`). Because of this, even though the proportion of M/F is relatively similar (32% F in group 1 and 34% in group 2), the p-value is extremely low when I run a chi-square test. Since I want to compare just `F` or `M` alone, no the entire group.

I haven't dealt with data like this before, so I'm not completely sure how to get around this and find a p-value based on the proportion/percentage rather than the count.

For reference, here are the values in each group

```
D1_F = 47
D1_M = 98
D2_F = 32
D2_M = 62
```

Would it be viable to just put the percentages into a data frame and run a chi-square test on that? Like this:

```
D1_F = 32.41
D2_F = 34.04

sex = data.frame(G1 = D1_F, 
                   G2 = D2_F)
chisq.test(sex)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to cv, Sarah :-).   
It is not clear to us what the hypothesis of your test is. If you test F or M only, you would compare the numbers of users of drug 1 and drug 2 in the F or M group. And these numbers are quite different, namely about 50% more use drug 1 than drug 2. This would explain the low $p$-value: you would test the hypothesis that the number of drug 1 users is the same as the number of drug 2 users.   
Your code indicates that you want to compare the proportion of female drug users in the two drug groups. Here you would get a high $p$-value (close to 1), because the  proport

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.

There is nothing to "get around"; chi square does not require even splits, and your split isn't particularly uneven.

Chi square is for counts. If you want to test the proportions within sex, you can use two t-tests. But this tests a different thing than chi-square. Your original tests whether sex is associated with drug. The latter tests whether men use the drugs in equal proportions (or, if you use women, whether women do).

Finally, running chi-square on your data results in a very high p value, not a very low one:

```
drug <- c(rep("A", 145), rep("B", 94))
sex <- c(rep("M", 98), rep("F", 47), rep("M", 62), rep("F", 32))
table(drug,sex)

chisq.test(drug,sex) # chisq = 0.01  p = 0.90
```

Comment: Why use two t-tests?

Comment: One for men, one for women.

Comment: But why a t-test?

Comment: That's pretty standard for testing proportions.